# Blurring image with SDL in C

Tags: c, sdl

I've got problem with algorithm, that should blur my image. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>

Uint32 getpixel(SDL_Surface *surface, int x, int y)
{
    int bpp = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;
    /* Here p is the address to the pixel we want to retrieve */
    Uint8 *p = (Uint8 *)surface->pixels + y * surface->pitch + x * bpp;

    switch(bpp) {
    case 1:
        return *p;
        break;

    case 2:
        return *(Uint16 *)p;
        break;

    case 3:
        if(SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN)
            return p[0] << 16 | p[1] << 8 | p[2];
        else
            return p[0] | p[1] << 8 | p[2] << 16;
        break;

    case 4:
        return *(Uint32 *)p;
        break;

    default:
        return 0;       /* shouldn't happen, but avoids warnings */
    }
}

void putpixel(SDL_Surface *surface, int x, int y, Uint32 pixel)
{
    int bpp = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;
    /* Here p is the address to the pixel we want to set */
    Uint8 *p = (Uint8 *)surface->pixels + y * surface->pitch + x * bpp;

    switch(bpp) {
    case 1:
        *p = pixel;
        break;

    case 2:
        *(Uint16 *)p = pixel;
        break;

    case 3:
        if(SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN) {
            p[0] = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
            p[1] = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
            p[2] = pixel & 0xff;
        } else {
            p[0] = pixel & 0xff;
            p[1] = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
            p[2] = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
        }
        break;

    case 4:
        *(Uint32 *)p = pixel;
        break;
    }
}


SDL_Surface* Filter(SDL_Surface* source)
{
    SDL_Surface *target;
    int x, y;

    if( source->flags & SDL_SRCCOLORKEY )
        {target = SDL_CreateRGBSurface( SDL_SWSURFACE, source->w ,source->h, source->format->BitsPerPixel, source->format->Rmask, source->format->Gmask, source->format->Bmask, 0 );}
    else
        {target = SDL_CreateRGBSurface( SDL_SWSURFACE, source->w ,source->h, source->format->BitsPerPixel, source->format->Rmask, source->format->Gmask, source->format->Bmask, source->format->Amask );}

    for(y=0; y<source->h; ++y){
        for(x=0; x<source->w; ++x)
        {
           int a = getpixel(source,x-1, y-1);
           int b = getpixel(source,x  , y-1);
           int c = getpixel(source,x+1, y-1);

           int d = getpixel(source,x-1, y);
           int z = getpixel(source,x  , y);
           int e = getpixel(source,x+1, y);

           int f = getpixel(source,x-1, y+1);
           int g = getpixel(source,x  , y+1);
           int h = getpixel(source,x+1, y+1);

           int avg = (a+b+c + d+z+e + f+g+h)/9;

           putpixel(target,x, y, avg);
        }
    }
return target;
}
```

And here are results of filtering:

[image: Befor]

[image: After]

I don't exactly know where is the problem coming from, because I thought that blurring means "Take 9 pixels around, compute average of them and put it in place", but that doesn't work.

Comment: `int avg = (a+b+c + d+z+e + f+g+h)/9;` doesn't look right. Separate the colors.

Comment: How should I separate the colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are a bit more complicated than your code assumes. Pixel values in the image are encoded using a particular *pixel format*, so you cannot just sum them up, divide and assume that everything will just work.

Instead, you have to separate the different channels of the image, operate on each channel separately, and then group them again. For that you can use the functions [`SDL_GetRGB()`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetRGB) and [`SDL_MapRGB()`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MapRGB):

```
unsigned r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
Uint8 rt, gt, bt;

unsigned a = getpixel(source,x-1, y-1);
SDL_GetRGB(a, source->format, &rt, &gt, &bt);
r += rt;
g += gt;
b += bt;
//repeat for each pixel...

r /= 9;
g /= 9;
b /= 9;
unsigned avg = SDL_MapRGB(target->format, r, g, b);
```

PS: Note that all these function calls will be quite slow. If you know the pixel format in advance, you can do the RGB conversion yourself.

PS2: Although this should more or less work, note that many color calculations work better if you take the Gamma into account, instead of assuming the colorspace is linear.

PS3: This algorithm is an order of magnitude faster if you do two passes. The first one will blur only the horizontal edge (3 samples), while the second one will blur the vertical one (3 more samples). That is `O(n)` instead of `O(n^2)`, being `n` the size of your blurring kernel.

PS4: As commented by other people, you are not checking the image boundaries nor locking the surface.